# Need help solving optimization problem in R

Tags: r, optimization, analytics, linear-programming

[image]

Here's my code:

```
install.packages("stats")
install.packages("RMySQL")
install.packages("lpSolveAPI")
library(lpSolveAPI)
library(readr)
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(RMySQL)


# Decision variables:
x = number of bushels A
y = number of bushels B

# Constraints:
x + 2*y ≤ 50 (Land)
2*x + 3*y ≤ 75 (Water)
3*x + 2*y ≤ 60 (Fertilizer)
x + 2*y ≤ 40  (Labor)

# Objective Function:
# Maximize profits 

lp_crop <- make.lp(0,2)
set.objfn(lp_crop, c(20, 30))
add.constraint(lp_crop, c(1, 2), "<=", 50)
add.constraint(lp_crop, c(2, 3), "<=", 75)
add.constraint(lp_crop, c(3, 2), "<=", 60)
add.constraint(lp_crop, c(1, 2), "<=", 40)

invisible(lp.control(lp_crop, sense = 'max'))
print(lp_crop)

solve(lp_crop)

# optimal amount of bushels to produce for each crop

v <- get.variables(lp_crop)
paste0('# A bushels', v[1])
paste0('# B bushels', v[2])
```

My question is about the last part. I was expecting to get the following:

```
## [1] "# A bushels 10"
## [1] "# B bushels 15"
```

Instead I get the following:

```
paste0('# B bushels', v[2])
# [1] "# B bushels0"
paste0('# A bushels', v[1])
# [1] "# A bushels0"
paste0('# B bushels', v[2])
# 1] "# B bushels0"
```

Why is my code not solving the optimization problem?

Comment: You cannot `install.packages("stats")`, it already is a base package, Several of the packages loaded in your *minimal* working example are not used in the MWE. As for the error, have you tried closing and rerunning R?

Comment: Just type  `v` and see what's actually there

Answer (score 1):

I am not able to replicate the erroneous print. Instead, when I run the following code, the only problem I see is a need to use `paste()` instead of `paste0()`.

```
library(lpSolveAPI)

lp_crop <- make.lp(0,2)
set.objfn(lp_crop, c(20, 30))
add.constraint(lp_crop, c(1, 2), "<=", 50)
add.constraint(lp_crop, c(2, 3), "<=", 75)
add.constraint(lp_crop, c(3, 2), "<=", 60)
add.constraint(lp_crop, c(1, 2), "<=", 40)

invisible(lp.control(lp_crop, sense = 'max'))
print(lp_crop)



> print(lp_crop)
Model name: 
            C1    C2        
Maximize    20    30        
R1           1     2  <=  50
R2           2     3  <=  75
R3           3     2  <=  60
R4           1     2  <=  40
Kind       Std   Std        
Type      Real  Real        
Upper      Inf   Inf        
Lower        0     0  

solve(lp_crop)

v <- get.variables(lp_crop)

v
```

The vector `v` contains two values, 10 and 15:

```
> v
[1] 10 15
```

The `paste0()` function does not add spaces between arguments to the function. To generate spaces between the arguments, use `paste()`:

Original code:

```
> paste0('# A bushels', v[1])
[1] "# A bushels10"
> paste0('# B bushels', v[2])
[1] "# B bushels15"
```

Now, use `paste()`:

```
> paste('# A bushels', v[1])
[1] "# A bushels 10"
> paste('# B bushels', v[2])
[1] "# B bushels 15"
>
```

Comment: Maybe I'm not properly communicating the problem...my code is not returning the answer 10 and 15. Whether I use paste or paste0, the result in the console is "[1] "# A bushels 0"" and 
"[1] "# B bushels 0""

Comment: @Hades - what happens when you print `v`?

Answer (score 1):

In base R you can use `constrOptim` function:

```
req <- matrix(c(1, 2,
                2, 3,
                3, 2,
                1, 2), 4, byrow =TRUE)

units <- c(50, 75, 60, 40)

v <- constrOptim(c(0,0), \(x)-x%*%c(20,30), NULL,-req,-units)$par
[1]  9.999983 15.000008
```

Notice that you are dealing with integer problem. Thus the solution should be integers. But here we have values that are quite not integers. Note that the optimization assumed that the values were continuous, thats why gave us the results above, which we can clearly see are `10` and `15`

Comment: Much cleaner and simpler approach.   That's good!